# Join vectors strings on Python

Tags: python, r

In `R` I can join together a vector of strings using `paste`:

```
> a = 1:3
> a
[1] 1 2 3

> b = 4:6
> b
[1] 4 5 6

> d = 7:9
> d
[1] 7 8 9

> together = paste(a, b, d, sep='-')
> together 
[1] "1-4-7" "2-5-8" "3-6-9"
```

How can i do the same in Python ?

Answer (score 7):

Vectorized operations in R can be approximated in Python by [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or the built-in function [map()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

Here, we use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to do parallel iteration over the three lists.

```
a = range(1,4)
b = range(4,7)
c = range(7,10)
together = ['-'.join(str(i) for i in z) for z in zip(a,b,c)]
```

Output:

```
>>> together
['1-4-7', '2-5-8', '3-6-9']
```

One subtlety in the above code is that the argument to join is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) which means it's evaluated lazily. To be even lazier, replace [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with [izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) package.

Answer (score 2):

How about your own function:

```
def f(*args):
    return '-'.join([str(a) for a in args])
```

and then `map`

```
map(f, a, b, c)
# ['1-4-7', '2-5-8', '3-6-9']
```

Or for fun (and any number of values):

```
map(lambda *args: '-'.join(map(str, args), a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

adding a one-liner assuming 3 element lists

```
l1 = range(1,4)
l2 = range(4,7)
l3 = range(7,10)

map(lambda x,y,z: '%s-%s-%s' % (x,y,z), l1, l2,l3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = range(1,4)
b = range(4,7)
c = range(7,10)

together = ['{}-{}-{}'.format(*x) for x in zip(a, b, c)]
```

EDIT:

`zip(a,b,c)` iterates over `(a[0], b[0], c[0])`, `(a[1], b[1], c[1])`, etc. Instead of using `['{}-{}-{}'.format(x, y, z) for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)]`, we can use `*` [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) as above.